# What is the most efficient way to reshape a 3d Array into a 2d with a specific order in julia?

Tags: julia

Consider the following Array:

```
julia> test_mat3 = rand(2, 3, 2)
2×3×2 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.539697  0.17689   0.944783
 0.537687  0.660573  0.19497

[:, :, 2] =
 0.726739    0.798789  0.0900478
 0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798
```

I want to reshape it into a 2d Array with a specific order. First, I want to concatenate **each row of each inner matrix** (here with shape 2x3). So for the first step, I expect several 1x6 inner matrixes. Second, I want to concatenate these matrixes vertically. The expected output on the `test_mat3` would be:

```
2×6 Array{Float64, 2}:
 0.539697    0.17689   0.944783    0.537687    0.660573  0.19497
 0.726739    0.798789  0.0900478   0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798
```

However, I wrote this code:

```
using SplitApplyCombine

function flatten_3d(arr::Array{Float64, 3})
    mat = zeros(
        Float64,
        size(arr, 3),
        size(arr, 1)*size(arr, 2)
    )

    for (idx, arr)=enumerate(splitdimsview(arr, 3))
        the_vec = vcat(eachrow(arr)...)
        mat[idx, :] = the_vec
    end

    return mat
end
```

The script does the job:

```
julia> flatten_3d(test_mat3)
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.17689   0.944783   0.537687    0.660573  0.19497
 0.726739  0.798789  0.0900478  0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798
```

But I wonder if there is any better way to do this? Any built-in function, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a package for figuring such things out. This one looks like:

```
julia> using TensorCast

julia> @cast mat[k,(j,i)] := test_mat3[i,j,k];

julia> mat == flatten_3d(test_mat3)
true
```

To read this:

- the 3rd dimension of the input is becoming the 1st dim of the output. It has a temporary name `k`.
- each "inner matrix" is indexed by `i, j`. Transposing would be `j, i`, and combining these into one dimension with `vec` would be `(i,j)`, in which `i` changes fastest (as arrays are column-major).
- in `(j,i)` it is `j` changes fastest, like transpose then vec. This is placed into the 2nd dim of the output.

What it produces (in this instance) is just `permutedims` then `reshape`. One way to use it is just a way to figure out the right permutation etc:

```
julia> @pretty  @cast mat[k,(j,i)] := test_mat3[i,j,k]
begin
    @boundscheck ndims(test_mat3) == 3 || throw(ArgumentError("expected a 3-tensor test_mat3[i, j, k]"))
    local (ax_i, ax_j, ax_k) = (axes(test_mat3, 1), axes(test_mat3, 2), axes(test_mat3, 3))
    local elephant = transmute(test_mat3, Val((3, 2, 1)))
    mat = reshape(elephant, (ax_k, star(ax_j, ax_i)))
end
```

This is in fact more like `PermutedDimsArray` plus `reshape`: by default this returns a view of the input, when possible, not a copy. This is very quick but the next operation may or may not be quick. To make a `Matrix` instead, it borrows a better algorithm for permutations from TensorOperations.jl, which is faster on large arrays:

```
julia> flatten_lazy(x) = @cast _[k,(j,i)] := x[i,j,k];

julia> flatten_eager(x) = @cast _[k,(j,i)] |= x[i,j,k];

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> let test_mat = rand(20,30,200)
         a = @btime flatten_3d($test_mat)
         b = @btime reshape(permutedims($test_mat, (3,2,1)), (200, 600))
         c = @btime flatten_lazy($test_mat)
         d = @btime flatten_eager($test_mat)
         a == b == c == d
       end
  956.708 μs (17002 allocations: 3.17 MiB)
  143.875 μs (3 allocations: 937.62 KiB)
  63.520 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)  # note the units, no time at all!
  53.291 μs (63 allocations: 942.45 KiB)
true
```

The package's documentation is here: https://mcabbott.github.io/TensorCast.jl/dev/basics/

Comment: Cool package! ( https://github.com/mcabbott/TensorCast.jl )

Comment: Thanks! I got tired of comments explaining to my future self why it was `(3,1,2)` here not `(2,3,1)`, etc... I am not sure this saved time overall...

Comment: Thanks. This package is great. From the date of this answer, I have been reading the doc. It would be the cherry on top if you improve it further with various examples.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should help:

```
using Combinatorics

test_mat3 = zeros(2, 3, 2);                                                                            
test_mat3[:, :, 1] =                                                                                   
  [0.539697  0.17689   0.944783 ;                                                                       
   0.537687  0.660573  0.19497 ]                                                                                                                                                                                       
test_mat3[:, :, 2] =                                                                                   
  [ 0.726739    0.798789  0.0900478;                                                                     
    0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798]

for p in permutations(1:3)
    A = reshape(permutedims(test_mat3,p),(2,6))
    @show p
    display(A)
end
```

Gives:

```
p = [1, 2, 3]
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.17689   0.944783  0.726739    0.798789  0.0900478
 0.537687  0.660573  0.19497   0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798
p = [1, 3, 2]
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.726739    0.17689   0.798789  0.944783  0.0900478
 0.537687  0.00744727  0.660573  0.837076  0.19497   0.25798
p = [2, 1, 3]
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.944783  0.660573  0.726739  0.0900478   0.837076
 0.17689   0.537687  0.19497   0.798789  0.00744727  0.25798
p = [2, 3, 1]
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.944783  0.798789   0.537687  0.19497     0.837076
 0.17689   0.726739  0.0900478  0.660573  0.00744727  0.25798
p = [3, 1, 2]
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.537687    0.17689   0.660573  0.944783   0.19497
 0.726739  0.00744727  0.798789  0.837076  0.0900478  0.25798
p = [3, 2, 1]
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.17689   0.944783   0.537687    0.660573  0.19497
 0.726739  0.798789  0.0900478  0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798
```

So, the requested permutation is:

```
julia> reshape(permutedims(test_mat3, (3,2,1)), (2,6))
2×6 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.539697  0.17689   0.944783   0.537687    0.660573  0.19497
 0.726739  0.798789  0.0900478  0.00744727  0.837076  0.25798
```

ADDENDUM: Why (3,2,1) ?

`permutedim` uses the permutation to make original axis #3 into axis #1 in new array (and overall `(3,2,1)` means 3=>1, 2=>2, 1=>3).

Julia considers columns as the first axis (rows are second). Which, incidently, is the reason why it is always preferable to read/write column elements sequentially for fast memory access.

In the OP `0.5396` and `0.7267` are the first *output* column, but in the *input*, are in the same row/col but different planes (third axis). So we permute axis 3=>1.

In the OP `0.5396` and `0.1768` are the first *output* row values, but in the *input*, are in the same row/plane but different columns (second axis). After the `reshape`, the second and third axes are combined, again, the earlier axis change fastest. We want to change from `0.53` to `0.17` first and not to `0.5376` (moving on the first *input* axis), so we permute axis 2=>2.

The third axis completes the permutation, and this explanation which is easier to grasp by following the numbers in the example of all permutations above than by reading ;)

Comment: `reshape(permutedims(test_mat3, (3,1,2)), (2,6))` doesn't make my expected output. Please pay attention to the specific order that I explained.

Comment: @Shayan sorry, too early to compare lists of numbers. Fixed the answer (this is the reason I had all the permutations laid out in the answer in any case).

Comment: It's ok! Thanks. Can you please provide the reason behind `(3, 2, 1)`?