# The perm argument in the permutedims Julia

Tags: julia

I can't fully understand how this argument affects the functionality of the `permutedims` function. I read the [official doc for this function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.permutedims) many times:

> permutedims(A::AbstractArray, perm)
> Permute the dimensions of array A. perm is a vector or a tuple of length ndims(A) specifying the permutation.

The first point that comes bold to me is that the `perm` can be a `Tuple` or a `Vector` **of length `ndims(A)`**. So if the `A` is a 3D Array, then `length(perm)==3` and so on. But, I can't understand how the permutation part takes place.
Then, Let's consider a similar example to what they brought in the doc:

```
julia> A = reshape(Vector(1:18), (3,2,3))
3×2×3 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

[:, :, 2] =
 7  10
 8  11
 9  12

[:, :, 3] =
 13  16
 14  17
 15  18

julia> permutedims(A, (3, 2, 1))
3×2×3 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  1   4
  7  10
 13  16

[:, :, 2] =
  2   5
  8  11
 14  17

[:, :, 3] =
  3   6
  9  12
 15  18
```

Since the above script is a little bit long in visualization, and hard to follow, I provided the results beside each other in the following picture:

[image]

I can see, for example, the first element of each `A`'s inner Matrix comes in the first column of each inner matrix of `permutedims`'s result. But I can't understand how the `perm=(3, 2, 1)` is doing that! How should I interpret the values of the `perm` argument (here, `(3, 2, 1)`)? **And, for me it gets much harder to figure it out when I try another example of `A` with different `ndims` and `size`!** I asked for an explanation about the `perm` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74430027/11747148), But I couldn't understand it either. So I decided to ask about it as a stand-alone question.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easier to see from the size than by looking at the printout. Making sure no two dimensions have the same size for clarity:

```
julia> x = rand(10, 20, 3, 4);

julia> permutedims(x, (1,2,4,3)) |> size  # exchange 3rd & 4th
(10, 20, 4, 3)

julia> invperm((1,2,4,3)) == (1,2,4,3)    # easy case, self-inverse
true

julia> y = permutedims(x, (4,1,2,3));     # move the 4th dim to be 1st

julia> size(y)
(4, 10, 20, 3)

julia> y[:, 7, 13, 2] == x[7, 13, 2, :]
true

julia> invperm((4,1,2,3))
(2, 3, 4, 1)

julia> permutedims(x, (2,3,4,1)) |> size  # put the 1st dim last
(20, 3, 4, 10)
```

For the 3D example above:

```
julia> A = reshape(1:18, (3, 2, 3));

julia> B = permutedims(A, (3, 2, 1));  # reverse order of dims

julia> A[1,1,:] == B[:,1,1]  # these are the red circles
true

julia> A[2,1,:] == B[:,1,2]  # these are the yellow circles
true
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this rule `A[*, ..., *, :] == B[:, *, ..., *]` stand for every example? No, I tried it. Look I got your point on the *size* perspective completely. But, still, I don't understand how you know `A[1,1,:] == B[:,1,1]` since it is not a comprehensive rule. So, there should be an exact formula there.

Comment: What example fails? The example with `1,1` may be misleading, as it hides the fact that these indices too are permuted.

Answer (score 2):

Since the official implementation of `permutedims` is quite optimized. It is sometimes instructive to rewrite an impelementation to mimic it for educational purposes. So here is one which might clear things a bit hopefully (though @mcabbott's answer is just as good and less cumbersome):

```
function toy_permutedims(M, perm)
    # verify proper input
    !isperm(perm) && error("perm must be perm. duh!")
    length(perm) == ndims(M) || error("perm must be of size ndims")

    # calculate new shape of output array
    newshape = [size(M, i) for i in perm]
    # output array is same number of elements...
    Mout = similar(M)
    # but different shape...
    Mout = reshape(Mout, newshape...)

    # go over all input elements (1,1,1),(2,1,1)...
    for I in CartesianIndices(M)
        # The crucial bit: permute indices into new array!
        Mout[(I[perm[i]] for i = 1:ndims(M))...] = M[I]
    end
    # phew! all done
    return Mout
end
```

The implementation recovers the result in the OP:

```
julia> toy_permutedims(A, (3,2,1))                          
3×2×3 Array{Int64, 3}:                                      
[:, :, 1] =                                                                                                              
  1   4
  7  10
 13  16

[:, :, 2] =
  2   5
  8  11
 14  17

[:, :, 3] =
  3   6
  9  12
 15  18
```

But perhaps the comments are helpful. Also debugging statements can be sprinkled more easily.

See other answer too.

Comment: Thanks. `reshape(Mout, newshape...)` shouldn't be `reshape!(...)`? I mean you reshaped the `Mout` but, you didn't bind it to any variable. So I guess you dropped the exclamation mark there.

Comment: I checked `reshape(Mout, newshape...)` through a debugger. The result is the same as `Mout`. So what's the point there?

Comment: @Shayan Yep. Forgot the `!`. This is why mcabbot note on having different dims is important. Fixing answer

Comment: Turns out no `reshape!` but `reshape` still works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to visualize that example as a cube made of various slices.
The rows are the first dimension, the columns are the second one and the depth of the cube, made by going across the various slices, is the third dimension.

Then it becomes clear that in that example the `perm` argument should be interpreted as "put in the new first dimension (columns) what was originally in the 3rd dimension (e.g. the "depth" vector 1,7,13), put in the new second dimension (rows) what was originally in the second dimension, put in the new 3rd dimension what was originally in the first dimension (e.g. the column vector 1,2,3 that now goes across the various slices)". A perspective of what I said on the same matrix you named `A`:
[image]

Basically, you put in the `perm` parameter the desired newly ordered list of the old dimensions.

Comment: I added a visual example of what I intuitively got from your textual example to your answer, and I hope this aligns with what you had in your mind.